# Saving & loading Data -String-

Tags: java

I need help finding a method to save some variables to a string that can be repeated in a text file, which will be stored in my `C:` drive. It will be storing data for multiple players.  For example:

```
int one = 0; //(will be set from a different file)
int two = 0; //(will be set from a different file)
int three = 0; //(will be set from a different file)
String PlayerName;(set from a different file)
```

Saves like:

```
(1, 2, 3, player 1);
(1, 2, 3, player 2);
(1, 2, 3, player 3);
etc.
```

Whenever it's called from a player's action it will save that string to a text file.

My save and load methods so far:

```
public class Offers {

    public static List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<Offer>(2000);

    public Offers() {
    }

    public static void saveOffers() {
        for (Offer offer : offers) {
            if (offer == null) {
                continue;
            }
            int id = offer.id;
            int item = offer.item;
            int amount = offer.amount;
            int price = offer.price;
            int currentAmount = offer.currentAmount;
            int removedAmount = offer.removedAmount;
            int type = offer.type;
            int completed = offer.completed ? 1 : 0;
            int aborted = offer.aborted ? 1 : 0;
            int currentPrice = offer.currentPrice;
            int slot = offer.slot;
            String owner = offer.owner;
            String VALUES(""+ id + "" + item + "" + amount + "" + price + "" + currentAmount + "" + removedAmount + "" + type + "" + completed + "" + aborted + "" + currentPrice + "" + slot + "" + owner + "");
        }
    }

    public static void load() {
        int id = stream.readShort();
        int item = stream.read();
        int amount = stream.read();
        int price = stream.read();
        int currentAmount = stream.read();
        int removedAmount = stream.read();
        int type = stream.readShort();
        boolean completed = stream.readShort() == 1;
        boolean aborted = stream.readShort() == 1;
        int currentPrice = stream.read();
        int slot = stream.readShort();
        String owner = stream.readString();
        if (id != -1)
            offers.add(new Offer(id, item, amount, currentAmount, removedAmount, price, type, owner, completed, slot));
            for (Offer l : offers) {
                if (l == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (l.id == id && l.item == item && l.amount == amount && l.currentAmount == currentAmount && l.price == price && l.type == type && l.owner.equals(owner) && l.slot == slot) {
                    l.currentPrice = currentPrice;
                    l.aborted = aborted;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you running into?  Your question states what you want to do, and shows the code you have, but does not say what is not working, and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: @Ryan, Please ask a question so people know what to answer. Right now your post is just an open ended post that just solicits opinion or discussion.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer useful, but you still haven't asked a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its not what you asked, but may i suggest using xml instead to save your data. It seems that your current data structure would be better supported in xml not to mention it would be waaaaaay easier to implement.

writing xml files is super easy. 
[as shown here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)

and reading is just as easy [see this.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

then you can save your data like so

```
 <saves>
       <players>
             <player1>
                  <data>x,y</data>
                  <data>name</data>
                  <data>level</data>
             </player1>
             <player2>
                  <data>x,y</data>
                  <data>name</data>
                  <data>level</data>
             </player2>
       </players>
</saves>
```

Comment: You could also replace the name with an id and load the name from a separate file accordingly

Comment: -1 This isn't answering the question and is primarily opinion based. When you have the reputation, you can post comments suggesting things like this, but it's not an answer.

Comment: i understand what you mean , but it is relevant... I dont understand how one is to get rep if they keep getting down voted for trying to help. To each his own i guess.

Comment: Typically one gets rep by answering the questions asked. I do appreciate that you're trying to help, but this isn't a discussion forum. The answers section is for answers to the question asked (or at least an alternative answer that solves the underlying problem).

Comment: Well actually this did help. I was looking for a way to save the information. I was confused on the best way to do it & this worked. Thank you.